# Facebook api return error

Tags: facebook

Excuse for my bad english...

I downloaded and installed the facebook connection API. I am redirected to Facebook but once the authorization granted on facebook I encounter the following error: 'My mistake'

script 'index.php'

```
<?php


      require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook_api/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '88xxxx29',
  'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);



      $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'user_location', 'user_about_me', 'user_birthday', 'user_actions.books']; // optional
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://www.mywebsite.fr/fb-login-callback.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Connexion</a>';

      ?>
```

script 'fb-login-callback.php'

```
<?php
session_save_path("sessions/");
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook_api/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '88xxxx29',
  'app_secret' => ‘xxxxxxxxxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
  if ($helper->getError()) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
    echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
    echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
    echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
  } else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    echo 'Bad request';
  }
  exit;
}

// Logged in
echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
var_dump($tokenMetadata);

// Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
$tokenMetadata->validateAppId($config['app_id']);
// If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
//$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
$tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
  // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
  try {
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
  } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {

    echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
    exit;
  }

  echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
  var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
}

$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

// User is logged in with a long-lived access token.
// You can redirect them to a members-only page.
//header('Location: https://example.com/members.php');

?>
```

Error returned : 
Acces token meta data contains unexpected app id.

But the id specified in the script is correct...

```
 Metadata
    object(Facebook\Authentication\AccessTokenMetadata)#13 (1) { ["metadata":protected]=> array(7) { ["app_id"]=> string(15) "88xxxx29" ["application"]=> string(13) “mywebsite" ["expires_at"]=> object(DateTime)#17 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2015-11-20 17:55:52.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(12) "Europe/Paris" } ["is_valid"]=> bool(true) ["issued_at"]=> object(DateTime)#18 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2015-09-21 18:55:52.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(12) "Europe/Paris" } ["scopes"]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(13) "user_birthday" [1]=> string(13) "user_location" [2]=> string(13) "user_about_me" [3]=> string(5) "email" [4]=> string(18) "user_actions.books" [5]=> string(14) "public_profile" } ["user_id"]=> string(17) "10207379116973089" } } 


**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Access token metadata contains unexpected app ID.'** in /home/wbs/www/facebook_api/Authentication/AccessTokenMetadata.php:329 Stack trace: #0 /home/wbs/www/fb-login-callback.php(53): Facebook\Authentication\AccessTokenMetadata->validateAppId(NULL) #1 {main} thrown in /home/wbs/www/facebook_api/Authentication/AccessTokenMetadata.php on line 329
```

Comment: It looks like your `Facebook\Facebook` setup and your access token are using different App IDs. Making sure you're using the right App ID in all of your code.

Comment: The array $config has not been defined in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You try to access the $config['app_id'] variable, but you have not defined that.
Try this out:

```
 $config =[
  'app_id' => '88xxxx29',
  'app_secret' => ‘xxxxxxxxxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ];
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook ($config );
```